# Download file from Amazon S3 bucket using Angular and node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-s3

I have to download Masters.xls file from Amazon S3 bucket when I click on Masters.xls(below in html page). 
Note: Masters.xls file is present in my AWS bucket.

My html code:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="DataImportControl">
 <div ng-click="downloadFile()"> Masters.xls</div> 
</div>
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';


angular.module('app')

    .controller('DataImportControl', ['$scope','$http' , function($scope, $http) {

       $scope.downloadFile = function(){


         $http.post('/getfile').success(function(data) {


                  console.log("success.."+data);

                     }).error(function(response) {

                      console.error("error in posting");
                      });

    };

    }])
```

Server.js:

```
app.post('/getfile', function(req, res, next){

 var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update(
      {
        accessKeyId: "my access key",
        secretAccessKey: "my secret key",
        region: 'my region'
      });


var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var s3Params = {
    Bucket: 'my bucket name',
    Key: 'Masters.xls'
};
s3.getObject(s3Params, function(err, data) {
if (err === null) {
   res.attachment('Masters.xls'); // or whatever your logic needs
   res.send(data.Body);
      } else {
   res.status(500).send(err);
      }

      });
});
```

It just sends data of Masters file in controller back. How can I make it as downloaded in user's downloads folder by default or wherever he wants ?

Comment: I think you need to add ContentType: your file type,
    Body:  your file,
    ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256',
    ACL : 'private',
    ContentDisposition: 'attachment; filename=' + fileName,
    ContentType: 'application/octet-stream' 
to your s3Params object. Check my post this might give you some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254298/how-do-i-force-download-video-in-angularjs-from-amazon-s3/26406793#26406793

Comment: what is 'Body: file' in params? what should be the file?